# append rows to existing table if new table contain new data python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

i have two dataframes.First one is reference df and the second one is new df.

Ref df:

```
data = {'Machine': ['M1','M2','M2','M4','M4'],
        'Type': ['A1', 'D1', 'D2', 'A2','A5'],
        'Prod/RT': [0.002315, 0.012500, 0.046154, 0.008333,0.030000]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

[image]

New df:

```
datanew = {'Machine': ['M11','M2','M22','M4','M44','M55','M21'],
           'Type': ['A1', 'D1', 'D2', 'A2','A5','B4','A2'],
           'Speed': ['L1', 'L2', 'L1', 'L7','L0','L9','L2'],
           'Weight': [12,45,87,45,83,25,23],
           'Prod': [200, 0, 180, 0,100,700,0],
           'RT': [43200,0,3900,0,15000,40000,0]}
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datanew)
df1['Prod/RT']=df1['Prod']/df1['RT']
df1
```

[image]

What i want to do is check the new df if it contains **new Machine and Type combination with 'Prod/RT' value append that as a new row to ref. dataframe**. if that **new Machine/Type combination contains a missing Value for 'Prod/RT'  then No need to update that entry.**

For example:
expected df should be:

[image]

i tried this using combine_first but didnt give the expected result.

Really appreciate your support !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `concat` then `drop_duplicates`

```
out = pd.concat([df,df1[df.columns]]).drop_duplicates().dropna()
  Machine Type   Prod/RT
0      M1   A1  0.002315
1      M2   D1  0.012500
2      M2   D2  0.046154
3      M4   A2  0.008333
4      M4   A5  0.030000
0     M11   A1  0.004630
2     M22   D2  0.046154
4     M44   A5  0.006667
5     M55   B4  0.017500
```